# Data Annotations being ignored in .Net Core/EF Core Model (MySQL Backend)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have created a Web API using .Net Core 1.1 and EF Core. The backend is a MySQL Database, so I have included the *"MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.6-IR31"* dependency in the project.json file.

I have a simple model in my project. I am trying to map the columns in my model to the columns in an existing database. So I am using Data Annotations. I have this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace PropWorxAPI.Models
    {
        [Table("files")]
        public partial class File
        {
            [Key]
            [Column("file_id")]
            public int FileId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Column("file_num")]
            [MaxLength(50)]
            public string FileNum { get; set; }
            [MaxLength(255)]
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I want property **FileId** to map to field **file_id** in the database. However, when I run the project, it complains that there is no field **FileId** in the database. It's almost as if my column mapping annotations are being completely ignored. Any ideas? Thanks...

Just in case, I am including my project.json file below:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.6-IR31",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue in ASP.NET webforms using an entity framework 6 data access layer. I would test in the data access layer via a console runner and walk it through outputting the sql created via context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s) and everything would match up. I would run the webform app and the SQL would try to use the class name as the table name and fail due to missing table. I changed to fluent API from data annotation. Now everything is working. I think you maybe onto something about this being an EntityFrameworkCore issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too, the only solution I could find was to use the fluent API to define mappings as opposed to annotations. E.g.

```
builder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("product").HasKey(m => m.Id);
builder.Entity<Product>().Property(p => p.DateAdded).HasColumnName("date_added");
builder.Entity<Product>().Property(p => p.ImageUrl).HasColumnName("image_url");
```

Hopefully support for annotations will be available soon.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to avoid using the Fluent API because I preferred column mappings to be handled on the actual properties so I built my own column mapping using reflection.

See the code in the `OnModelCreating` function for the relevant parts.

**Note** I was using MySql and the code isn't 100% tested.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        private string _connectionString;

        public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

        public DatabaseContext(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(_connectionString);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // I couldn't get attribute mapping to work, so I
            // had to do the mapping programmatically myself.
            // Ideally we'd remove this code an rely on the
            // built-in code to handle it, but we need to wait
            // for MySql to support mapping in EF Core.

            var type = typeof(Entity);
            var properties = type
                .GetTypeInfo()
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                               BindingFlags.Instance | 
                               BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(property.Name);

                var ignore = property.GetCustomAttribute<NotMappedAttribute>();
                if (ignore != null)
                {
                    modelBuilder
                        .Entity(type)
                        .Ignore(property.Name);

                    continue;
                }

                var column = property.GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>();

                if (column == null)
                {
                    modelBuilder
                        .Entity(type)
                        .Property(property.Name)
                        .HasColumnName(property.Name);

                    continue;
                }

                modelBuilder
                    .Entity(type)
                    .Property(property.Name)
                    .HasColumnName(column.Name);

            }
        }
    }
}
```